# Using XSL to transform Excel XML

Tags: xml, excel, xslt

I need to transform an Excel XML spreadsheet so that I can then import it into another programs. With a normal XML document I have no problem doing that, but the Excel XML document is another matter. Where I am having a problem is extracting the data I need from each cell.
There has to be some incantation that I am unaware of that will allow me to traverse the tree in order to get the data. 
Here is what a part of my stylesheet looks like:

```
<xsl:template match="ss:Table"> 
<xsl:for-each select="ss:Row">
  <Reload>
     <xsl:value-of select="ss:Cell/ss:Data"/>
  </Reload>
  <vio_sta-id>
     <xsl:value-of select="ss:Cell/ss:Data"/>
  </vio_sta-id>
  <vio-first>
     <xsl:value-of select="ss:Cell/ss:Data"/>
  </vio-first>
  <vio-middle> 
      <xsl:value-of select="ss:Cell/ss:Data"/>
  </vio-middle>
  <vio-last>
      <xsl:value-of select="ss:Cell/ss:Data"/>  
  </vio-last>
```

Here is a "row" from the document that I am receiving.

```
   <ss:Row>
<ss:Cell><Data ss:Type="String">Reload</Data></ss:Cell>
<ss:Cell><Data ss:Type="Number">21</Data></ss:Cell>
<ss:Cell><Data ss:Type="String">ANTHONY</Data></ss:Cell>
<ss:Cell><Data ss:Type="String"></Data></ss:Cell>
<ss:Cell><Data ss:Type="String">VALDEZ</Data></ss:Cell>
<ss:Cell><Data ss:Type="String">01/28/1982</Data></ss:Cell>
<ss:Cell><Data ss:Type="String">07318386</Data></ss:Cell>
<ss:Cell><Data ss:Type="String">000-00-0000</Data></ss:Cell>
<ss:Cell><Data ss:Type="String">Blank Field</Data></ss:Cell>
<ss:Cell><Data ss:Type="String">638 W BAETZ</Data></ss:Cell>
<ss:Cell><Data ss:Type="String"></Data></ss:Cell>
<ss:Cell><Data ss:Type="String">SAN ANTONIO</Data></ss:Cell>
<ss:Cell><Data ss:Type="String">TX</Data></ss:Cell>
<ss:Cell><Data ss:Type="String">78221</Data></ss:Cell>
<ss:Cell><Data ss:Type="String">06/21/1999</Data></ss:Cell>
<ss:Cell><Data ss:Type="String">3259</Data></ss:Cell>
<ss:Cell><Data ss:Type="Number">165.00</Data></ss:Cell>
<ss:Cell><Data ss:Type="Number">0.00</Data></ss:Cell>
<ss:Cell><Data ss:Type="Number">0.00</Data></ss:Cell>
<ss:Cell><Data ss:Type="String">8880</Data></ss:Cell>
<ss:Cell><Data ss:Type="String">New</Data></ss:Cell>
<ss:Cell><Data ss:Type="String">00/00/0000</Data></ss:Cell>
<ss:Cell><Data ss:Type="String">PENDING</Data></ss:Cell>
<ss:Cell><Data ss:Type="String">FRED NIETO JR.</Data></ss:Cell>
<ss:Cell><Data ss:Type="String">ZIMMERMAN  #700</Data></ss:Cell>
<ss:Cell><Data ss:Type="String">EXP. 1-99::NEW::0</Data></ss:Cell>
<ss:Cell><Data ss:Type="Number">10</Data></ss:Cell>
<ss:Cell><Data ss:Type="Number">5</Data></ss:Cell>
```

My output consists of the data from the first cell repeated over and over.. Somehow,I need to read the node-set and then advance to the next one...

thanks

Comment: I recommend you sanitize your sample.  It appears to contain a real user's personal information.

Comment: I suggest you stop and learn about namespaces and namespace prefixes before proceeding.

Answer (score 0):

**UPDATE**.  I missed your last statement on my first reading.

Your approach has two basic problems:

1. You are iterating through the rows, but not the cells.
2. You are not selecting a specific `Data` element.

Your template should look like this:

```
<xsl:for-each select="ss:Row">
        <Reload>
            <xsl:value-of select="ss:Cell[1]/ss:Data"/>
        </Reload>
        <vio_sta-id>
            <xsl:value-of select="ss:Cell[2]/ss:Data"/>
        </vio_sta-id>

   <!-- etc -->

</xsl:for-each>
```

(Original answer.  Leaving this in case it still helpful to understand.)

The `Data` elements are not prefixed:

```
<ss:Cell><Data ss:Type="String">06/21/1999</Data></ss:Cell>
```

But your selectors are prefixing them with `ss`

```
<xsl:value-of select="ss:Cell/ss:Data"/>
```

This will not work unless the default namespace happens to also have the same URI as the `ss` prefix.

Try rewriting the selector as

```
<xsl:value-of select="ss:Cell/Data"/>
```

Comment: That's not doing what I am wanting to do. If i change the stylesheet to the example provided, I get a listing

Comment: THat does not work. I change to the suggested stylesheet and i get <reload>Reload</<reload> and then all of the text, then <reload>Jesse</reload>.    I do not think the for-each cell is what I need to do.. 
I want to read the row element, and then read each cell for that data that it holds..

Comment: Ok   I took your example and took out the XSL:For-each for the cells and then simply used the brackets for the cells .i.e ss:Cell[1] and it provides me the data that I am looking for. I am thinking that going in to the DATA level was too deep for indexing but sure am not an XPATH guru by any means..